# CSS Box-shadow Missing on Foreground

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the CSS box-shadow in the header class to overlap the navbar below it. The shadow appears behind the header but it is not visible on the bottom. The full example is a three column page layout with a header, nav bar and body content footer. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pboulos/pen/EEPZQV)

```css
/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 18px 5px red;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#" style="float:right">Link</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the normal behaviour, as elements will, be default, lay on top on their previous sibling. Use `position: relative;` on your header and navigation elements, and set the z-index accordingly (higher on the header than the menu) to override the default behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 18px 5px red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#" style="float:right">Link</a>
</div>
</body>
```

You simply add `position: relative` (or you could use `absolute` or `fixed`, but in this case, it would break the layout. z-index only works on 'positioned' (that is, one with any position other than static) elements).

So, to put it simply, you to position you `.header` and give it a `z-index` that is higher than `.topnav`. As `.topnav` has no z-index, a z-index of 1 works fine for the `.header`.

Experiment and read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

add

```
z-index: 1000;
```

to header class and then

```
z-index: 900;
```

to topnav class

z-index essentially is the index of how close or far it appears to you. the closer to zero you get the 'flatter' it will appear and i believe 1000 is the highest in the other direction. usually i set my navbar or whatever top level component i have to z-index 1000 and then go down from there.